# React onClick not firing on first click, second click behaves as expected (simple debug message doesn't appear until second click)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I introduced a bug at some point (live version doesn't have this issue) but haven't been able to figure out what caused it.

I have a button in React (it's just a `div` with an `onClick`).

The button has an `onClick` and a `:hover` CSS effect.

The button is loaded by clicking on another `div` (which works on the first click).

After loading the button (and its wrapper content), the button doesn't do anything on the first click. Without doing anything else, clicking again let's it work fine.

Currently I have a debug message in my `onClick`, so it looks something like this

```
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        console.log("ONclicked! " + this.props.alt);
                        // e.stopPropagation();
                        // various callbacks
                    }}>
```

I also have similar `console.log` debug messages on all of the button's parents, *all the way up to the root React element* (i.e. clicking anywhere on the page shoots out a message, except when clicking on this particular button the first time). Even the root element does not register anything on the first click..

None of these messages appear on the first click.

Again, *without doing anything else*, just clicking one more time in the same spot fires the `onClick` as expected.

Other questions about "first click not working" I've seen are all about the state not updating on the first click. In my case I'm not even trying to update the state, I don't seem to be getting the `onClick` called at all.

I've looked through all the commits for this version and still haven't been able to figure out the problem. Any ideas on what can cause this behavior? The weirdest part to me is that the second click works, while the first doesn't seem to do anything. But nothing about the state/DOM is changing between the first and second click (since the first click doesn't seem to be registered at all). I think this rules out things like a misconfigured `pointer-events` CSS rule?

Edit:

Upon further exploration, it seems that the first click actually triggers `onMouseEnter`, which seems totally nuts lol... But I added a `console.log` to `onMouseEnter` and it's definitely triggering exactly when I make the first click, and NOT on subsequent clicks.

Edit 2:

But this mouseEnter thing only happens in Firefox, not Chrome. But the first click not working bug is in both browsers.

Edit 3:

`onMouseDown` is firing properly, but `onClick` still only happens on the second time the button is clicked (at which point `onMouseDown` has fired twice).

Also, double checked and confirmed that I don't use `stopPropagation` anywhere which seems to be a common source of this problem.

Comment: Could you make a small repo in codesandbox or similar that reproduce your behavior?

Comment: Been trying since you commented but haven't been able to reproduce. I think if I were able to reproduce it I would probably be able to fix it myself, I'm sure it's just some small thing interfering with the click. Will keep trying for now as it's a good way to debug as well.

Comment: Still not reproduced, but I tested more and found that the first click is triggering `onMouseEnter` for some reason... (the later clicks that work don't trigger `onMouseEnter`).

Comment: Another finding, `onMouseDown` is triggering properly. Guess I can switch to that if needed. Also, there is no usage of `event.stopPropagatiion()` in the entire codebase.

Comment: Without providing us with either a repro (which you've stated you haven't been able to do as of yet) or the full code surrounding the referenced elements, we'd only be speculating. My guess is that you've got another listener somewhere that's intercepting the event the first time.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a listener issue! Not exactly intercepting, but a setState() call in another (non-parent/child) div's onBlur event was preventing onClick from being called. Answered myself with more detail!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figured it out!

In another adjacent div, I had an `onBlur` handler. In that handler, I called `setState()` on the component (hiding another `div` when that `div` is unfocused).

To show the button that was having issues, I clicked in something in the `div` with the `onBlur`. This gave it focus. When I did a first click outside on the button that appeared, it triggered `blur`.

Apparently, the `setState()` call interfered with the click in some way, including causing the weird behavior I described with `mouseEnter` being retriggered. Perhaps the `setState` caused a redraw, which then caused `mouseEnter` to be fired again? Maybe the quick redraw also stops the `onClick` from going through, even though `mouseDown` is fired? (something to do with event ordering?) I'm still not sure why exactly that happens.

But after removing the `setState()` call, the first click on the button works as expected.

And thus ends a couple hours of painful debugging.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm not even using React but I had an onBlur handler that was ultimately causing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, in your onClick function you have to persist your event.

```
 onClick={(e) => {
     e.persist();
     console.log("ONclicked! " + this.props.alt);
     // e.stopPropagation();
     // various callbacks
 }}>
```

see this link for more explanation on the subject: https://deepscan.io/docs/rules/react-missing-event-persist

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Intellij` or `WebStorm` this happens when running `javascript debug` mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** check whether the state is getting updated on the first click, if not fix that.

**Secondly** add the persist event to your onClick,

```
 onClick={(event) => {
 event.persist();
 console.log("ONclicked! " + this.props.alt);
```

}}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).